# Beautiful Soup - Finding first link in an article

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm creating a python solution to [this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Getting_to_Philosophy) but I'm having trouble getting past some edge cases.

The problem I'm running into arises for a page like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Greek) where [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Greek) is the one that should be extracted since it is the first one outside of the parentheses. Conversely, some articles are [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diglossia) where the link appears before the first parenthesis.

The way I'm handling these cases currently is by initially iterating through the elements and text in the first paragraph tag (stringified version) and checking to see which is found first between a '(' and an `<a>`. If `<a>` is found first (meaning before a parenthesis has been reached), I just take that link. If a parenthesis is found first, I wait until the parentheses are closed and then take the following '

In effect, I am just getting the direct child of the first paragraph element which could be done with something like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
soup.select_one("#mw-content-text > p > a")
```

What I think would work here is to use such a select statement to find the first link in the prefix from the beginning of th `<p>` until the first parenthesis or (if there isn't a link in the prefix) find the link immediately following the close parenthesis using something similar to what I'm doing currently:

```
`findNext('a').attrs['href']`
```

If such an approach is to be used, a multiple issues arise including:
1. How to actually get the prefix up until the first parenthesis with only the direct child elements of the '

**Is there a streamlined way to do this? If there is a better approach, what would it be?**

Comment: How about re-formulating the problem like "get the first link that is not inside the parenthesis - either before or after them"?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem reminds me that popular algorithms&data structures problem when you need to check if parenthesis or other brackets are balanced. For these kind of problems, a *stack data structure* is convenient to use.

So, in this case, we'll *push to stack if there is an opening parenthesis and pop from it if there is a closing one*. The valid link for us would be the one when the *stack is empty*:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag


urls = [
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Greek",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diglossia"
]

with requests.Session() as session:
    for url in urls:
        response = session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        stack = []
        for child in soup.select_one("#mw-content-text > p").children:
            if isinstance(child, NavigableString):
                if "(" in child:
                    stack.append("(")
                if ")" in child:
                    stack.pop()

            if isinstance(child, Tag) and child.name == "a" and not stack:
                print(child.get_text())
                break
```

It prints `dialects` for "Modern Greek" page and `linguistics` for "Diglossia". Both cases are handled.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the reminiscence it has of the matching parentheses problem as well. The solution I originally had did something similar. This is a very creative solution! I don't know the library functions that well and it seems like they really simplify the code.

Comment: Actually, for an article like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States) the main body is not the first `<p>` tag, it's the second. How can the main body be uniquely identified? So many edge cases! lol

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 interesting! What if we get the first `p` after the `table` element if it exists and if not, we'll get the very first `p` element in the "content" element..?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 btw, have you considered using the python wikipedia API clients?..

Comment: Idk, there were seemingly an incalculable number of edge cases to handle. If you're curious, [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/159648/reaching-the-philosophy-wiki-page) is what I ended up doing.